# Using UFW with ipsets

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a VPS for business purposes.  The firewall is setup using ufw; testing reveals that it's working well.  I'd like to further secure my server using techniques described here:

http://blog.ls20.com/securing-your-server-using-ipset-and-dynamic-blocklists/

Are there any known conflicts between UFW and ipsets that might cause problems if I were to use ipsets to block malicious hosts attempting to probe my server for vulnerabilities?  I understand that ufw makes configuring iptables simpler.  My primary concern is the impact on ufw.  Are there any known issues with using multiple apps to setup iptables?

Answer (score -2):

This might not answer your question directly, however...

Why not use PFsense or IPfire rather? They can do all you need and more.

[PFSense](https://www.pfsense.org)

[Ipfire](http://www.ipfire.org/)

Comment: I'm familiar with PFSense - I use it at home.  I do not want to use a full fledged firewall & IDS on the VPS; I want to block known malicious hosts. I looked up IPFire and appears to be overkill for my use case.